# how to automate reverse tunnel in with crontab: syntax error

Tags: syntax, ssh, sh, tunnel, raspberry-pi

I am following a tutorial on how to run a reverse ssh tunnel which is found at http://wiki.fabelier.org/index.php?title=Permanent_Reverse_SSH_Tunneling
Issue I am having is when I run the tunneling.sh script:

```
a=(`ps -ef | grep 19999 | grep -v grep`)
if [ ! "$a" ]; then
    ssh -fN -R 19999:localhost:22 <middle-usename>@<middle-hostname>
fi
```

I receive this error:

```
tunnels.sh 1: tunnels.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I am a extreme newbie to shell scripts in linux so please be kind.

Comment: No need for the parentheses around the back-tick quoted command line.

Comment: @twalberg, thanks that did it. Feel free to answer to get the accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error with this:

```
a=(`ps -ef | grep 19999 | grep -v grep`)
```

It should simply be:

```
a=`ps -ef | grep 19999 | grep -v grep`
```

There's no need for parentheses there, although there is an alternate syntax to accomplish the same thing:

```
a=$(ps -ef | grep 19999 | grep -v grep)
```

Note the addition of the `$` and that the backticks are no longer necessary.

Comment: now I get tunnels.sh: 2: tunnels.sh: a: not found. Also if ports are already open the reverse tunnel tries to fire anyways